# Toggle button/switcher to open a URL

Tags: jquery, button, slider

I've this jquery:

```
<div class="slider-frame">
    <span class="slider-button">Change</span>
</div>
```

```js
$('.slider-button').toggle(function() {
    $(this).addClass('on').html('Home');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on').html('Away');
});​
```

For the full code see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vY7SQ/155/).

I need that when users change the button status (home -> away and vice versa) it opens a URL, e.g. when I slide on Away, I need to open `www.mysite.com/away` and when I slide on "Home" It open `www.mysite.com/home`.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Where do you want to open the url ? Have you tried anything using iframes or window.open ?

Comment: I want open the url in the same page. I'm a really a jquey noob ... I try with window.open but seems not work. maybe I apply it wrong ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location` would direct the user to the url in the same window, whereas `window.open()` will open it in a new window.

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vY7SQ/157/

FYI - this is not jQuery code, but pure JS - so you can use it even when jQuery is not attached.

Im curious, though - what's the point of having a cool animated toggle slider switch if the user will just be directed away from it as soon as it's clicked? Perhaps you are trying to load new content onto the current page without (re)loading the page?

Comment: Thx ! It seem to work :-) If I want to set a default state on "Home" , how I can do it ?

Comment: Yes. I need to show some products in the page. If the button is on "Home" it's load the "mysite.com/products/home" . After that I need that "home" was 'selected' in the reloaded page .. Any idea ..?

Comment: This should really be asked in a seperate question, but since it's a quickie... just add the class `on` to slider button. `<span class="slider-button on">Change</span>` See: http://jsfiddle.net/vY7SQ/160/

Comment: Thx ;-) However I need to change something , because now the button it's always set on "Away" .

Comment: see my updated comment above. Jsfiddle ending in 161 - use `toggleClass('on')`

Answer (score 1):

"open" is a broad term.  You could do something like this:

```
$(this).addClass('on').html('Home');
window.location = '/home/';
```

...but that would reload the page.  Do you mean to open a popup?

```
window.open('/home/');
```

...or do you want to reload the page and keep the toggle selected?  You can either use a cookie or look at the URL on page load.

Comment: I need to open in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

see if you want to open another page at current page use ajax or iframe:

```
$('.slider-button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Change" || $(this).text() == "Away") {
        $(this).addClass('on').html('Home');
        $('#yourdivToloadContent').load('mysite.com/products/home');
    } else if ($(this).text() == "Home") {
        $(this).removeClass('on').html('Away');
        $('#yourdivToloadContent').load('mysite.com/products/away');
    }
});
```

checkout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WM8xS/

Comment: This is a grat solution ... but I dont want to use iframe. I like that the content is displayed in the same page ... can you help me?

Comment: I need to show products on my page. So If I slide to "Home" I need to see "mysite.com/products/home" and if I'm on "Away" "mysite.com/products/away"

Comment: see the updated answer. use the `.load` method. and populate the results in a div.